# iterate through DataFrame in R to change columns types

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I come from Python and I am not sure how to accomplish this in `R`. I want to write a function that takes two arguments. A `dataframe` and `a list of column names`. I want iterate through the dataframe to convert the column names that match the ones in the list.

the list of column names I want to convert, the type is `character`

```
col.names<-c('Ri','Na','Mg')
```

I wrote this function but it is not returning the desired output

```
    function.convert<- function(df,col.names){
  for (i in colnames(df)) {
    if (i %in% col.names){
      as.factor(i)}
}}
```

my desired output is the same dataframe but with specified columns converted to factor type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df[col.names] <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(df[col.names], as.factor))
```

or using `dplyr`

```
df %>% mutate_at(col.names, as.factor)
```

---

Or as a function

```
f <- function(df, col.names) {
    df[col.names] <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(df[col.names], as.factor))
    df
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can I modify this line of code to add it to the function? I would like it to be a function.

Comment: Yes. You can always pass column names and the potential col type as arguments.  However, unless you expect to use it multiple times across your code, writing a function for this may be an overkill.

Comment: Hi Leena. I agree with @Drj. I think a function doesn't increase readability here. Notice also how succinct the `dplyr` approach is. Either way, I've made an edit.

Comment: @Drj Thank you for your input. I plan to use it many times that is why I prefer a function.